# Reverse connect(listening mode) in VNC on Windows CE and Window Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, vnc

I was looking for solution of Reverse connect by using VNC on Windows CE and Windows Mobile.
As far as I know, only few VNC was porting on WinCE and the most popular one that I think is http://efonvnc.sourceforge.net/ Thanks for the author.

However, it is pretty good vnc server on WinCE but not including reverse connect function (aka VNC listening mode) which let vnc server side connect to vnc viewer side whereas viewer connect to server.

I had found another one VNC called MobileVNC for Windows Mobile, unfortunately it is not open source..

Did any one know other VNC can do reverse connect on Windows CE OS?
Or I did wrong way of using efon VNC to reverse connect?
I had tried such as, winvnc.exe -connect IP:port, winvnc.exe -service -connect IP:port, winvnc.exe -service_run -connect IP:port, but all of them doesn't work at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there was a Windows CE porting of LibVNC (http://libvnc.github.io/), you may use it as a starting point to write your own server, implementing the features you need.